# Sharing a controller instance across multiple RenderAction methods in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In asp.net mvc, I return a `View(Main.cshtml)` from a Controller Action. My Controller is called `SampleController.cs`. Within the `Main.cshtml` view, I render other Actions BAction and CAction by calling `Html.RenderAction("BAction", "Sample")` and `Html.RenderAction("CAction", "Sample")`.
I notice that every time `RenderAction` is called within the main view, a new instance of the `SampleController` class is created. I confirmed this by logging information into a text file in the constructor of the class.

I understand that each http request creates an instance of the Controller and there is not much that can be done about it. Is there a way to share the Controller instance across the `RenderAction` methods within the same http request?

Comment: That's how the framework works. Each request creates a new controller instance. What are you trying to accomplish with a shared instance?

Comment: Yes, I understand that each request creates a new controller instance. My question is: how can I share the controller instance within the same request? I have some calculated instance fields which I would like to re-use. I understand that I can always use .NET cache and request cache. But I am wondering if there is a way to share the controller instance across the RenderAction calls within the same request. I edited the question to be less ambiguous

Comment: `RenderAction` will create a new controller instance. If your goal is to pass data then use a model class and pass it into a `Partial` or `RenderPartial`.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that there is no way to do what I asked for. Thanks for your response Jasen!